# Ferret search not working for my rails app

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-3, ferret, acts-as-ferret

First, I logged into the `ruby script/console -e production` and tried to index each table using

```
Model.rebuild_index
```

It worked fine and returned `true`

I then started the ferret server using the command

```
ruby script/ferret_server start -e production
```

Then i started my application and it's all working fine except the search. When i try searching on the search tab, i get an error as follows :

```
Words::BadWordnetDataset in HomeController#search

Failed to locate the wordnet database. Please ensure it is installed and that 
if it resides at a custom path that path is given as an argument when 
constructing the Words object.
```

The search is working fine in the console

`result = ActsAsFerret.find("admin",[User], :limit => 2)` does fetch me results

Comment: Maybe try replacing will_paginate with the gem?

Comment: So how should i go about it?? where should i make the changes?

Comment: on the second thought it's nothing to do with will_paginate.  I don't think ActiveRecord::Base doesn't even method rebuild-index.. Unless it's your own implementation of cause.

Comment: I think its a method of the gem Wordnet usef to index data in the database. But i am not able to install the Gem Wordnet also      http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7950903/not-able-to-run-install-gems-using-gemfile

Comment: Why would you like to rebuild the index? Changing the index is difficult, and if it is working, why to renumber it?

Comment: Could this possibly be a permissions problem in the file system? Just a wild guess really.

Comment: @muistooshort : what are you trying to say? Its working fine in the console. and am using wordnet gem in my app but not getting where exactly am getting the bug!!!

Comment: Does Ferret write any files to the file system? Is your console and the web server running as the same user? The "works for me but not the server" symptom often indicates a file system permissions issue and that would explain the "Failed to locate the wordnet database." error. I'm just throwing some ideas out, hence a comment rather than an answer.

Comment: @muistooshort: so what should i do to get rid of this? which file permission settings should i change?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Installed the copy of the wordnet data files for OS using :

```
sudo apt-get install wordnet-base
```

Word is actually derived from Wordnet :

```
require 'word'
data =  Words::Wordnet.new
```

Answer (score -1):

Nothing surprising
ActiveRecord has no method rebuild-index

Comment: I think its a method of the gem Wordnet usef to index data in the database. But i am not able to install the Gem Wordnet also      http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7950903/not-able-to-run-install-gems-using-gemfile