# Not able to run/install Gems using Gemfile

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-3, rubygems, ruby-on-rails-3.1

When i give bundle install or bundle exec i am getting this error

Could not find gem 'acts_as_ferret-0.4.4.gem (>= 0) ruby' in any of the gem sources listed in your Gemfile.

Apparently the first gem in the Gemfile is acts_as_ferret-0.4.4 and source is

source 'http://rubygems.org'

I tried other sources also but still not working!!!

Comment: Please insert the part of your Gemfile that you think leads to the error (and try to indent by 4 spaces to format it). The problem is in your Gemfile, so we need the sources to help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As Pete is saying there probably is a problem with your gemfile
Try to open it and see if your acts_as_ferret looks something like this.

```
gem "acts_as_ferret", "~> 0.5.3"
```

if not try and change it to the above

There is more info to be found on the gem on the github page
https://github.com/jkraemer/acts_as_ferret

Comment: you are right it was initially like 'acts_as_ferret-0.4.4.gem' i made the change as gem "acts_as_ferret", "~> 0.5.3"

Answer (score 0):

Looks like your gem identifier is misstyped if it cannot be found even if you try different sources. Did you try to remove the `(>=0)` ? I think that just says, 'get me any version' but you already specify the version as 0.4.4. Also I'm not too sure about the 'ruby' addition. 
[Here](http://rubyforge.org/frs/?group_id=2916&release_id=34998) the gem is listed as `acts_as_ferret-0.4.4.gem`